# An error occurred creating the form when Debugging code

Tags: c#, .net, biometrics

Hy friends

I had developing  a application to fetch data from a biometric fingerprint machine but when I run it in VS2010  its complete build sucessfully and then gives an error

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message="An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00853A19-BD51-419B-9269-2DABE57EB61F} failed due to the following error: 80040154."
  Source="CardManagement"
  StackTrace:
       at Card.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T Instance) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 190
       at Card.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_Card()
       at Card.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm() in C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Desktop\card\Card Management\My Project\Application.Designer.vb:line 35
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at Card.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

CAn any one help I am running out of time.I spend 6 hrs reading related post

Comment: It sounds like you don't have all of the files installed to run that COM object.  Does the device work in another app on that computer?

Comment: This is a module developed by may senior who left the company .its running perfectly on that system and iam able to debug and run application on that machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya I have solved ...This error occur because the com dll Zmkeeper.dll was not able to register .I tried it manually using regsvr32 but failed.At last I installed the demo software package which came along with the software which register all the wanted dll and after that added the dlls again as reference .It worked.but now also I dont know why i cannot do the same by regsvr32

Answer (score 0):

Please try to download all the SDK as with Zkemkeeper, it not able to register using Regsvr32 as its not able to to get all other required dlls.

Following is the url for downloading SDK for zkemkeeper.

www.findthatzip-file.com/search-18066782-hZIP/winrar-winzip-download-fpsdk.zip.htm

download it and copy all the dlls in to System32 for 32-bit and same for 64-bit and perform Regsvr, this will work now.

Answer (score -2):

another solution : is to register the Com By yourself as in this link:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2012/03/05/referencing-32-bit-com-components-in-sharepoint-2010-after-upgrade-from-sharepoint-2007.aspx

this way you should do it in the target machines.