# Retrieving the COM class factory for components with CLSID - Class not registered

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, com, zkemkeeper

I am trying to run my Windows Application (**winForm**) on a PC (**OS Win7, 64 Bit**) but it showing me **this error** or exception:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for components with CLSID
>   {00853A19-BD51-419B-9269-2DABE57EB61f} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I google and found that I should need to **Build for x86 (Althought current window is 64 bit).** I did this but getting the same error. After that now I trying to install **zkeeper** dependency but getting this error:

[image]

> The Module D:\TheSDK\zkemkeeper.dll" may not compatible with the
>   version of windows that you are running. Check if the moduel is
>   compatible with an x86 or x64 version of regsvr32.exe

Here is batch file (Dependency SDK installer) :

```
cd /d %~dp0
if /i "%PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER:~0,3%"=="X86" (
    echo system is x86
    copy .\*.dll %windir%\system32\
    regsvr32 %windir%\system32\zkemkeeper.dll

    ) else (
        echo system is x64
        copy .\*.dll %windir%\SysWOW64\
        regsvr32 %windir%\SysWOW64\zkemkeeper.dll

    )
```

Update: Even I try to run and install manually both `regsvr` of system32 and 64 and still getting same error.

Comment: According to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/deva/2010/09/27/error-message-on-64-bit-windows-when-you-try-run-regsvr32-exe/ you need to use the right version of regsvr32

Comment: That .bat file is wrong, it must use c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe.  Pretty scary btw, dumping so many files into the operating system directory is quite unhealthy.  There is a nuget package for it, it might do less damage.

Comment: @BugFinder I try to directly register but still the same error. Tried System32 and Syswow64 regsvr but same issue.

Comment: @HansPassant i used C:\windows\System32>regsvr32 D:\TheSDK\zkemkeeper.dll but still getting the same error.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah i have tried with C:\Windows\Syswow64\regsvr32 D:\TheSDK\Zkemkeeper.dll but still the same error message.

Comment: Sometimes the registration fails because the DLL itself (or any of its dependencies) has missing or broken dependencies. If you are willing to dig deeper, [download](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies/releases) and run  [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) on zkemkeeper.dll and look for any red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what was the problem but maybe it was related to .Net framework. After installing the [developer pack of .Net Framework 4.5.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637). I deleted my SDK and register all the dependency (DLL) again. Then, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the com dll Zmkeeper.dll was not able to register. In some cases, it might need to be registered along with a typeLib file. Also, there could perhaps be some custom installer action performed if it goes through an installer. Seems like a demo version installation solved the problem. checkout this issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20190348/10907141)